# DRF: Serializer update method returns KeyError during partial update, instead of ValidationError raised by model clean() method

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, I'm testing one of the endpoints for proper exception handling. A `ValidationError` is expected but instead a `KeyError` is returned. I've been trying to debug this case for a while now so here's the step-by-step breakdown of what happens:

**Step 1:**
Incoming data gets serialized:

```
class BatchIdView(APIView):
    ...
    def patch(self, request, batch_id):
        ...
        serializer = BatchSerializer(batch, data=data, partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(data=humps.camelize(serializer.errors), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

There are no custom validators in this serializer and data is validated during this step (`is_valid()` method returns `True`)

**Step 2:**
Attempting to update the object (actually this code comes directly following previous snippet):

```
        try:
            serializer.update(batch, serializer.validated_data)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return Response(data=humps.camelize(e.messages), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(data={"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
```

**Step 3:**
During the `update()` method, model's `save()` method triggers validation:

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if condition:
            raise ValidationError({"field": "error text goes here"})
```

I've double-checked that this `raise ValidationError()` line gets triggered in that particular test case.

**Step 4:**
Instead of returning the validation error, the serializer decides to trigger `to_representation()` method which is customized and is checking for another field:

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        response_data = copy(data)
        ...
        response_data["product_type"] = {"current": data["product_type"]}
```

---

**Conclusion**
The problem is that this only happens when I'm passing data that triggers validation error in the model. When I'm passing correct data, the `to_representation()` works as expected and takes the entire model data instead of the incoming partial data.

---

**Logical question**
Why doesn't serializer return ValidationError from the `clean()` method and how to make it return the ValidationError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that it's possible to update multiple fields on the model and then attempt to save it with this code below. It updates all the fields validated by the serializer.

```
for field, value in dict(serializer.validated_data).items():
    setattr(batch, field, value) 
batch.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `serializer.update()` method directly as it is not a recommended approach.

Edit:
Rather, after `serializer.is_valid()` use `serializer = SerializerClass(batch,partial=True)` and then use `serializer.save()`

Comment: Do you mean to call the model method `save()` and then run the resulting object through serializer? Cause that seems like a more appropriate option. There is no point in assigning `serializer` again after it's already been declared and validated.  
Additionally, `serializer.save()` method doesn't return `ValidationError` error either, it doesn't return any error at all.

Comment: `serializer.save()` does return a model instance and does not throw any errors. If you call `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`, then in this case, the validations will be run and the function `validate` on the serializer will be called. Then `serializer.validated_data` will contain the data returned from `validate` method.

Comment: Yea, but that triggers serializer validations and not model validations. Either that or it doesn't return model level errors.